# SQL Middle of the Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I know you can set @Date to `01/01/2001` as beginning of the month.

and then call dates that are first of every month, for example:

```
01/01/2001
01/02/2001
01/03/2001
```

but how would I please if possible is always find the date in the middle of the month? I would use 15th, but issue you have is with February

I need to make analysis of sum of sales mid month

any ideas please team

Comment: In most cases, it's more sensible to just use the 15th for these sort of things. That way, at least, the first "half" of each month is directly comparable. Of course, it means that the second half of each month is of variable length and so those values are not directly comparable - but that's inevitable because we have variable length months. How fair is it to compare February's 1st - 14th results to every other month's 1st - 15th results, if you do it your way either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have tried the following

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, (datediff(DD, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), - 1), eomonth(getdate())) / 2), DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), - 1)),
    CEILING((datediff(DD, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), - 1), eomonth(getdate())) / 2.00))
```

An update to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010270/sql-middle-of-the-month/53010376#53010376)

```
    DECLARE @Date DATE ='2018-10-01'---'20180201'

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, CEILING((DAY(EOMONTH(@Date)) / 2.00)) - 1, @Date)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this formula

```
DECLARE @Date DATE ='20180201'

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, (DAY(EOMONTH(@Date)) / 2) - 1, @Date)
```

Comment: It's worth adding that (DAY(EOMONTH(@Date)) / 2) - 1 is truncated to int.

i.e. it's always 15 except Feb

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Get the count of the days in the month and calculate the "middle" day. In the next example the count of the days (28, 29, 30 or 31) is divided by an integer divisor (2), so the result will be an integer that has any fractional part truncated. Choose your preferred method.

```
DECLARE @date date 
SET @date = DATEFROMPARTS(2020, 2, 1)

-- 15 is the half of the month with 30 and 31 days, 14 for months with 28, 29 days
SELECT DATEDIFF(d, @date, DATEADD(month, 1, @date)) / 2
-- 16 is the half of the month with 31 days, 15 for months with 29, 30 days, 14 for month with 28 days
SELECT (DATEDIFF(d, @date, DATEADD(month, 1, @date)) + 1) / 2
```

**Example:**

```
WITH Months AS
(
    SELECT SomeDate = DATEFROMPARTS(2018, 1, 1)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, SomeDate) 
    FROM Months 
    WHERE DATEPART(month, SomeDate) < 12
)
SELECT 
    SomeDate AS FirstDate, 
    DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(month, 1, SomeDate)) AS LastDate,
    DATEDIFF(d, SomeDate, DATEADD(month, 1, SomeDate)) AS DaysBetween,
    DATEDIFF(d, SomeDate, DATEADD(month, 1, SomeDate)) / 2 AS HalfOfMonth1,
    (DATEDIFF(d, SomeDate, DATEADD(month, 1, SomeDate)) + 1) / 2 AS HalfOfMonth2
FROM Months
```

**Output:**

```
FirstDate   LastDate    DaysBetween HalfOfMonth1    HalfOfMonth2
01/01/2018  31/01/2018  31          15              16
01/02/2018  28/02/2018  28          14              14
01/03/2018  31/03/2018  31          15              16
01/04/2018  30/04/2018  30          15              15
01/05/2018  31/05/2018  31          15              16
01/06/2018  30/06/2018  30          15              15
01/07/2018  31/07/2018  31          15              16
01/08/2018  31/08/2018  31          15              16
01/09/2018  30/09/2018  30          15              15
01/10/2018  31/10/2018  31          15              16
01/11/2018  30/11/2018  30          15              15
01/12/2018  31/12/2018  31          15              16
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that get start date of month and end date of month by using datediff you can find the number of day to add and subtract

```
Set @tdate = '02/10/2018';
Select DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@tdate),MONTH(@tdate),1) as startdate , dateadd(day,-1,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@tdate),MONTH(@tdate)+1,1)) as enddate
```

Regards